# How to update html content of an element with angular function?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a table fulfilled with `ngFor` directive.

Each line has a title, a badge (Material badge) and a button.
I would like to change `matBadge` value when I click on my button.

The function returns a value that I would like to set it in the `matBadge` of the current line, not others.

Is there a way to pass my current line badge in my function, to update value?

**UPDATE**

Here is part of my HTML code work throw For loop :

```
<table *ngFor="let layer of items">
    <li>
        <div [id]="layer.id">
            <button [matBadge]="indexLayer">Toggle</button>
            <button (click)="this.utilsService.changeIndex('raise', layer, $event)"> change </button>
        </div>
    </li>
</table>
```

What I would like is identify my div with id and pass it throw my function (something like `$event`) to update my `indexLayer` which is different for each line

Thanks !

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding) should be something that would help

Comment: Probably you want to pass the index as an argument to your function, and based on the index change the badge.

Comment: I have an id on my table row, I want to pass my line by identifying it with id to change badge value

Comment: A kind of `function($('#id'))` in jquery js, but with angular structure

Comment: Well you are not presenting any code.... but in your click event, pass then the id... something like `(click)="myFunction(item.id)"` in your template. You really need to provide a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Sorry, in fact its for work and I do not have internet on my development computer, that is why I cannot share my code, because I have to rewrite it. But i will try

Comment: I updated my post, so there is part of the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found another solution to achieve my purpose

I had an attribute in my `utils.service.ts` file :

```
public indexList: Map<String, String> = new Map();
```

my function is like :

```
changeIndex(layer){
    imageryLayers.raise(layer);
    this.utilsService.indexList.set(layer.id, imageryLayers.indexOf(layer));
}
```

Something like above works fine.

And my html :

```
<button [matBadge]="this.utilsService.get(layer.id)"> Toggle </button>
```